# Using byPair in D

Tags: tuples, d, associative-array

I am trying to work through the example given at http://dlang.org/library/std/array/by_pair.html

But I keep getting the error `Error: no property 'byPair' for type 'int[string]'`

Is there something I need to be importing that I am not?

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.array;
import std.file;
import std.conv;
import std.regex;
import std.typecons : tuple, Tuple;
import std.algorithm : sort;

void main(string[] args)
{

        auto aa = ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3];
        Tuple!(string, int)[] pairs;

        // Iteration over key/value pairs.
        foreach (pair; aa.byPair)
        {
            pairs ~= pair;
        }

        // Iteration order is implementation-dependent, so we should sort it to get
        // a fixed order.
        sort(pairs);
        assert(pairs == [
            tuple("a", 1),
            tuple("b", 2),
            tuple("c", 3)
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest D version.

`byPair` was added in 2.067.0:

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/2842

Answer (score 0):

`byPair` is not an inherent property of associative arrays.
You need to import `std.array : byPair` or just `std.array`.

I guess that, because the example is shown in the documentation for `std.array`, it is assumend that the user will import `std.array`.

Comment: my bad, i did have it imported. still have the issue.